# google maps / проблема при вставке / отображается только маркер

Tags: api, google-maps-api, google-maps

Господа, вставляю карту, но отображается только маркер.

API подключил. На локалке всё работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может проблема в хостинге? beget

Answer (score 0):

Хостинг точно ни при чем. Судя по картинке, в консоли браузера должно быть написано ...No API key...

Руководство Google по получению ключей [здесь](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key?hl=ru).